# why pop up screen is not open in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to open pop up screen I am getting this error :

**

```
Error: Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal
    at Error (native)
    at file:///C:/Users/asd/Desktop/angular/angularproject/angular.js:2682:42
    at Object.getService [as get] (file:///C:/Users/asd/Desktop/angular/angularproject/angular.js:2810:39)
    at file:///C:/Users/asd/Desktop/angular/angularproject/angular.js:2687:45
    at getService (file:///C:/Users/asd/Desktop/angular/angularproject/angular.js:2810:39)
    at invoke (file:///C:/Users/asd/Desktop/angular/angularproject/angular.js:2828:13)
    at Object.instantiate (file:///C:/Users/asd/Desktop/angular/angularproject/angular.js:2860:23)
    at $get (file:///C:/Users/asd/Desktop/angular/angularproject/angular.js:4743:24)
    at file:///C:/Users/asd/Desktop/angular/angularproject/angular.js:4322:17
    at forEach (file:///C:/Users/asd/Desktop/angular/angularproject/angular.js:140:20)
```

why I am getting this error ..here is my Html and js files ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.2.0.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="DialogDemoCtrl">
    <div  header-info innerHtm="inner_text"></div>
    <a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="" ng-click="openPopupScreen()">Add Contend</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**

Here is my js file :

```
var myApp = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
myApp.directive('headerInfo', function(){
alert('dd')
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        scope: {
            inner_htm: '=innerHtm'
        },
        templateUrl:'dialog.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


            console.log(scope.inner_html);
            console.log(element);
            console.log(element.html());
            scope.inner_htm = element.html();
            console.log(scope.inner_htm);

        }
    }
})

myApp.controller('DialogDemoCtrl',  function($scope, $modal, $log) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.activeItem = {
        id:'',
        name: '',
        content: ''
    };

    $scope.addItem = function () {
        $scope.activeItem.id = $scope.items.length + 1;
        $scope.items.push($scope.activeItem);
        $scope.activeItem = {}; /* reset active item*/

    };

    $scope.getId = function (item) {
        alert('ID: '+item.id);

    };
    $scope.openPopupScreen = function () {
        alert('---')
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            template: $scope.inner_text,
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl
        });

    };

});
```

here us Dialog.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h1>Add Element</h1>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form >
        <label>Name:</label><input type="text" class="span3" ng-model="activeItem.name"></br>
        <label>Content Name:</label><input type="password" class="span3" ng-model="activeItem.content"></br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addItem()">Add In List</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn ">Clear</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">close</a>
</div>
```

I don't know why I am getting this error  ..I am too frustrated from this error ?

Comment: can you setup a plunker

Comment: I never use plunker ,,can you use just copy and paste my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the problem $modal was added in 0.6.0

```
<script src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.2.0.js"></script>
```

please use latest version

Answer (score 0):

Please see here : http://plnkr.co/edit/0u9YyKkkaRIwnuazqFwC?p=preview and add code below to your app.js

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($scope, $modalInstance) {

    $scope.ok = function() {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```